# Accessing array in one component and modifying the same in other component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to have an array(2d) object consisting of various img srcs based on different types and that array needs to be stored in the separate js file. 
Then in one class component, I just want to import the array and use it to count the number of src of each type *(this part is implemented)*, in another class component I want to have a method that adds more src (or objects) in that array and which should trigger re-rendering of that class component (but only the updated src should be re-rendered).

How should I maintain that array and how to make a function to modify that array?

Should that array be inside a class component which can be later imported in other class components? if so, then how we will simply import the array and on the same hand from another class component, modify that array?

P.S: I am trying to make a photography portfolio where I am having various types and in each type, I want to show the number of photos present and as an admin right add more images in a particular type.

For code, part refer: https://github.com/vkushal28/exp_click
(**allCategories.jsx** is my array object file, **categories.jsx** is to display number of counts (*already done*), **allPhotos.jsx** here I have to populate images based on the type and modify the array object (some trial statements have been used in this, please ignore) )

Comment: Don't use a separate JS file to store the array, that's what a database is for. Have your server provide an API to read and update the database. When the user updates the array, have your app forward the change to the server, then update your React app accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try to maintain it in a database now, I just want to know whether I can modify that array located in separate js file from another class component? does react allows?

Comment: In general, if you want component A to modify component B: 1) lift up the state to the common parent 2) pass a modifier function to A 3) pass the state as prop to B.